# Pass rails variable into js erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, controller

I'm using FAYE to broadcast chat messages without having to refresh the page, and it works if I hardcode the channel. But I want to pass in a variable from my messages controller and use that as the channel to broadcast to, that way I can have private chats between 2 people

In app/views/messages/create.js.erb

```
<% broadcast @channel do %>
$("#chat").append("<%= escape_javascript render(@message) %>");
<% end %>
$("#new_message")[0].reset();
```

If I change @channel to "/messages" it will work correctly and my messages will show up on the screens of all people currently viewing the "/messages" channel, instantly, after the message is stored in the database.

In my messages controller I have

```
def private
 ...

@channel = "/"+@id1.to_s+"chatwith"+ @id2.to_s

 ...

end
```

This makes it so that each two-person chat has a unique channel that only they have access to. Other users aren't allowed on the page and don't have access to that channel, which is what other code in the controller accomplishes.

I just need to make @channel accessible in create.js.erb every time a message gets sent, so it gets broadcasted to the correct, private channel for that specific chat.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have defined the `@channel` inside a private method, so it cannot be accessed by the view, move the `@channel` variable inside a public method or make the existing method public

```
def <my_method>
  .......
  @channel 
  .......
end
```

Comment: that is not the case. the method may be called "private", but that doesn't mean it is a private method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using a respond_to in my controller. At first, I tried using it in the privatechat method of my messages controller, which didn't end up working. But I noticed that the respond_to call in my create method of my messages controller was working, and it was how the messages were being passed to create.js.erb and broadcasted when I hardcoded the channel. So I decided to declare @channel in the **create** method instead of the privatechat method of the messages controller, and now all is working how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the variable value in the appropriate controller action, and it will be available to any view file matching the action name (in the appropriate views subfolder - e.g. articles_controller with create action corresponds to create.js.erb file in the views/articles folder)